# Simple sort for form result of select2 (js) form element?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery-select2

Im using [select2](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2) by ivaynberg and have an issue with how the data is returned when submitting.

Is there any way to get the results in the form submit data in the order in which they where selected in the select2 element without using the sortable drag and drop solution?
Lets say there are three options:

```
<option name=red value=red>red</option>
<option name=blue value=blue>blue</option>
<option name=green value=green>green</option>
```

and in a multiple select2 element, the selection is made as green then red (in the rendered element, green sits in front of red). When submitting the form the array returns:

```
[select2] => Array
 (
  [0] => red
  [1] => green
 )
```

in the order they appeared in the initial html data.
But I would like to record the order of which the user selected these values by outputting the submit data in the selected order like this:

```
[select2] => Array
 (
  [0] => green
  [1] => red
 )
```

Any switch or option in select2 I can use to do this? (a bit of a JS novice, so I did not understand all the  documentation provided with this awesome function).

Answer (score 0):

I got an excellent code snippet from jdecuyper posted on my original thread on the select2 github issue page:

> If you access directly the selected items inside the multiple select
>   then you can read the elements in the order they got selected:
>   http://jsfiddle.net/jdecuyper/zx7vZ/

```
$("#m1").select2();

$("#submit_selection").click(function () { 

    var selectedItems = "";
    var selectedItemIds = "";
    var separator = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < $("#m1").select2("data").length; i++)
    {
        selectedItems += separator + $("#m1").select2("data")[i]["text"];
        selectedItemIds += separator + $("#m1").select2("data")[i]["id"];
        separator = " ";
    }
    $("#m1selectedItem").val(selectedItems);
    $("#m1selectedItemIds").val(selectedItemIds);

});
```

Add a hidden attribute to the text input that collects the ordered IDs (or values) on submit and it works like a champ.